# Trying to run Script for Oracle 11g Database as System

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, system

I just installed Oracle 11g Express and wanted to run a script, but it says I have insufficient access.
Does the system user not have superuser access from the start?

Below is a list of the commands I was trying to issue.
 Is there a way to make sure that my system user have sufficient privileges to run these commands ?

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.DBMS_REPUTIL TO SYSTEM with grant option
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.DBMS_EXTENTS TO SYSTEM with grant option
```

Comment: you have to login with `sys as sysdba` then it must work

Comment: Who is *it* who says you have insufficient access. Does *it* also give an error message?

Comment: Exhausted, thanks so much. That worked perfectly!